# Run a function in the background while starting another function

Tags: java

I want to run a function in the background which checks every seconds a url.
I already have the function to check the url but I want to run this function every second and meanwhile I can start functions manually.
I hope you understand my question.

Thanks

Comment: See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule(java.util.TimerTask, java.util.Date, long)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the right moment for you to use threads

[Introduction to threads in java](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-04-1996/jw-04-threads.html)

Here's what you need to do:
In your program , before you start your manual functions and when you want to start checking that url , start a thread that loops every second which runs that url checking function.
In the main program , after you've started the thread , you can start running your manual functions

Comment: Did you look up the date : 04/01/96